# An example of a generalized Cantor set with positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I want to know if there exist a set $ X\subset \mathbb R$ such that $X$ is

$i)$ Perfect

$ii)$ Compact

$iii)$ Has empty interior

$iv)$ Totally disconnected

$v)$ Is not countable

But $X$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

The sets that are defined with the above properties are called *generalized Cantor sets*.

Please could you tell me how to construct an explicit example?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Volterra-Cantor_set) contains an explicit construction with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.  Simply modify the construction of the standard ternary set in such a way that you remove an increasing proportion of the remaining intervals with each step.

Note that it's *not* enough to simply remove a greater proportion than 1/3.  You've got to remove an *increasing* proportion so that the total length of the removed intervals is less than one.

There's a nice discussion of this in Stromberg's *Classical Real Analysis*.